# Translucent Dialog Theme for Holo

Tags: android, android-layout

Can someone help me in finding the theme `Holo` Equivalent of

```
 @android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar
```

I tried using

```
@android:style/Theme.Holo.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar
```

but it's not Translucent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it :-)

```
@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog
```

Comment: You might want to use Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog instead of forcing Holo. ;)

Answer (score 9):

I think it's better to define your own theme than to use Theme.Holo.Dialog since it enables windowIsFloating. Something like this would be a better equivalent.

`<style name="CustomActTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>`

Comment: Working fine with activity. Thanks :)